# MVC Bootstrap Modal EditForm not all data displayed correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, bootstrap-modal

Working on a MVC Bootstrap-Modal to Edit Dogs.
Problem is not all data is correctly displayed in the View.

Before Refactoring I used a [httpGet] Iactionresult on the Index to return me a Edit.cshtml, containing an editform, and returning to Index.cshtml after a [httpPost] on the Edit.csthml, using a asp-route-Id to select the correct dog to edit.

After Refactoring I'm using a BootstrapModal on the Index to Edit the Dog(s) of the currently logged in DogOwner. I got  4 fields to Edit: Name, Fertility, Description, InstagramUrl. Name and InstagramUrl are being displayed as expected, Fertility and Description not.

Next snippet comes from Index.cstml where i use a Foreach (var item in Model.Dogs) for every dog of the currently logged in User:

```
     <div class="editWrapper">
                            <h3> Edit @item.FirstName</h3>
                            <form method="post" asp-controller="DogOwner" asp-action="EditDogPost" asp-route-dogId="@item.Id">
                                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
                                <div>
                                    <label asp-for="@Model.EditDogViewModel.FirstName"></label><br />
                                    <input asp-for="@Model.EditDogViewModel.FirstName" value="@item.FirstName" style="width:180px;" /><br />
                                    <span asp-validation-for="@Model.EditDogViewModel.FirstName"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <label asp-for="@Model.EditDogViewModel.DogFertility"></label><br />
                                    <select asp-for="@Model.EditDogViewModel.DogFertility"  asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList(typeof(DogFace.Domain.Model.Enums.DogFertility))" style="width:180px;">

                                        <option value="@item.DogFertility"></option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <label asp-for="@Model.EditDogViewModel.Description"></label><br />
                                    <textarea asp-for="@Model.EditDogViewModel.Description" style="width:500px;" value="@item.Description"></textarea><br />
                                    <span asp-validation-for="@Model.EditDogViewModel.Description"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <label asp-for="@Model.EditDogViewModel.InstagramUrl"></label><br />
                                    <input asp-for="@Model.EditDogViewModel.InstagramUrl" value="@item.InstagramUrl" style="width:500px;" /><br />
                                    <span asp-validation-for="@Model.EditDogViewModel.InstagramUrl"></span>
                                </div>
                                <br />
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.EditDogViewModel.Dog.Id" value="@item.Id" />
                                <input type="submit" value="Save" />
                            </form>
                        </div>
```

If i change the Textarea-tag for Description into Input-tag, the correct data is visible, for the FertilityDropdown, i got not clue (in the Enum: Infertile = 0, Intact = 1)

As you can see on the screenshots, Data for Textarea Description is loaded in correctly. (value= Benny is de max!)

snippet EditDogViewModel:

```
    public class EditDogViewModel
{
    public int DogId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "First name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Fertility")]
    public DogFertility DogFertility { get; set; }       
    [Display(Name = "Bio"), DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Description { get; set; }      
    [Display(Name = "Instagram")]
    public string InstagramUrl { get; set; }
    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
    public Domain.Model.Dog Dog { get; set; }

    public EditDogViewModel()
    {
    }
}
```

this is the modal button:

```
         <h3>
                        <a id="editDogButton" class="pointer">@item.FirstName</a>

                    </h3>
```

Feel free to ask more codesnippets if needed, or find them at http://pepijncappoen.visualstudio.com/DogFace

Thanks for any pointers or tips!

[image: DogProfile plus EditModal]

[image: Browser-debug]

Comment: Hi Xing Zou, and thanks for your comment... just included the Modal Button, the modal itself was already in the question (left out some divs for readability). Did not get any different outcome with your suggestion though